# Why does the probability of a binary outcome change with changes in the logistic model?

Tags: probability, logistic, python, predictive-models

I am trying to predict whether a lightning strike starts a fire or not. In that regard, I am trying to calculate the probability of a lightning strike to start a fire. One variable is binary (`polarity`) and I change it to `0` representing negatively charged lightning strikes and `1` represents positively charged lightning strikes. The logistic model (`bcc`) is:

```
print(bcc)
Intercept -2.2241e+01
Polarity  -1.5398e-01
Amplitude -1.8666e-03
```

and the average probability is calculated:

```
probability = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(-2.224109e+01 + (bcc.amplitude * -1.866664e-03) + bcc.polarity_dummy * -1.539889e-01)`
print(probability.mean())
0.00043334521395529236
```

I realise, I made a mistake and the `0` actually represents positively charged lightning strikes, and the `1` is negatively charged lightning strikes. The model does not change considerably, only the `polarity` changes from negative to positive:

```
print(bcc_new)
Intercept -2.2241e+01
Polarity   1.5398e-01
Amplitude -1.8666e-03

probability = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(-2.224109e+01 + (bcc.amplitude * -1.866664e-03) + bcc.polarity_dummy * 1.539889e-01)`
print(probability.mean())
0.0004833008259756023
```

Now the probability changes from `0.0004` to `0.0005`.

While the former is 'correct' in my opinion, I still struggle to understand why the probability changes so substantially (in relative terms) when the model does not really change. The ratio of negatively : positively charged lightning strikes are the same, the polarity coefficient changes to positive, when the positively charged lightning strikes are represented by `1` and negative vice versa.
So why does the probability change so much? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: The change from $0.0004$ to $0.0005$ might be from $0.000449999$ to $0.000450001$ (so minimal) or from $0.000350001$ to $0.000549999$ (almost a $60\%$ increase).  In fact your changing the sign of the polarity coefficient increases the odds (and here the probability) for those with `bcc.polarity_dummy` by about $36\%$ though the effect on the mean depends on what proportion are marked with this dummy combined with their other features.

Comment: The coding of the variable has no effect on the true predicted probability. What you are seeing is probably just a rounding error. Trying using the coefficient values stored in the model object rather than copy and pasting the values printed.

Comment: And when I now put the exact numbers derived. Do you still see these things as rounding errors? And the changing of the sign of the polarity coefficient is not done by me but through a cross-validated logistic regression.

Comment: Does polarity_dummy or the variables it's derived from have any missing values? do you have imputation behind it?

Comment: @Noah, I only added the coefficients and probabilities with fewer decimals for the readability of the reader. The reality is that I have used the entire coefficient saved in the model, and the calculated probabilities with lots of decimals are now added in the question. Does that help solving this?

Comment: I don't understand how the encoding can be a "mistake": isn't it up to you?  Anyway, can you provide the code used to fit the models?  Should the second code box have `bcc_new.polarity`, etc. in the `probability` calculation?

Comment: @rayven1lk. No there are no missing values for the `polarity_dummy` that have been filled out.

Comment: @BenReiniger, yes indeed it is up to me, and thereby also a human mistake, where `positive` was set to `0` and vice versa. Therefore, the `polarity` coefficient is positive in the latter example. I do not understand why that gives me such a different mean probability.

Comment: @Thomas, if you were to take the difference of the 2 sets of probabilities (or regression output with logit transform) for each observation, do they differ by the same amount?

Comment: it's also odd your intercept had not changed, usually it adjusts if you invert the definition of your binary variable